# Rewrite url by adding new word .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, apache2.4

My url is `mydomain/product`

I want to rewrite it in this way: `mydomain/category/product`

I tried these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/$1
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the `access_log` to see what it's getting rewritten to?

Comment: What URL are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: hey.. about "access_log" to be honest so many lines can't understand much, actually i have page product with url = mydomain/product , all i want is to edit the url  and add its category  so that looks like mydomain/category/product, knowing that didnt create a folder named category! i just want it to be with a rule in .htaccess if its possible.